# How to write redirect application in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I need to move all requests from one domain to another. I want to change part of URL, like subdomain.olddomain/url -> subdomain.newdomain/url.

I was sure that this is piece of cake and wrote Application_Begin request as:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        string from = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["from"];
        if (url.IndexOf(from) >= 0)
        {
            url = url.Replace(from, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["to"]);
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            if (url.IndexOf("error.aspx") < 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(url));
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, I forget, that BeginRequest started only when file physically exist.

Any ideas, how I can make such redirect in asp.net without creating hundreds of old pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a tool like ISAPIRewrite [http://www.isapirewrite.com/] to manage this for IIS 6, or the built in URL Rewriting for IIS7.

No reason to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Ok, but what are you rewriting from and to?  It sounds like you would have to map all misses to a single redirect page.  If so, I'm not sure that's an ideal usage of this tool.

Comment: "IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 enables Web administrators to create powerful rules" - This is great tool but it took sooooo long to find proper settings

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but I think if you uncheck the [`Check that file exists`](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iis+check+that+file+exists) option in IIS, it should work. How you do this depends on the IIS version.

Comment: This seems to be the way for me. On ASP.NET development server everything works just fine.

Comment: The issue is that in IIS, check described in post http://forums.iis.net/t/1114839.aspx is unchecked :)
So, locally it starts with BeginRequest, on live - with error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify an ASPX to run on 404 errors.  That page can perform the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this on the DNS level. I would redirect with a permanent 301 redirect to ensure that your search engine rankings are not affected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  A 301 redirect is HTTP.  DNS might mean creating an alias to the previous hostname which points to the new server.